# За получить адрес сайта без доменного имени?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью javascript получить адрес сайта без доменного имени?

Comment: [location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
alert(window.location.pathname);
```

[Вот документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) по window.location

Answer (score 1):

```js
let x = 'www.google.com/lalala';
let arr = x.split('/');
console.log(arr[1]);
```

Comment: А если будет `http://www.google.com/lalala`, получим пустую строку?

Comment: Тогда уж что-то вроде `arr.shift(); console.log(arr.join('/'))` в пути ведь может быть более одного слеша?

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = 'www.google.com/lalala';
let rep = /www..*..*\//;
let newStr = str.replace(rep, '');
console.log(newStr);
```